# Locking a thread by user

Tags: c#, locking

I need a way to lock c# threads by user

I have my data object and I create new instance for every user.
Every user has several threads that use this object and in I.O. operations I want to lock this object instance for this user only.
Using simple Lock {} is locking all the object instances, there for blocking other user.

I need some simple solution.

**Edit**

I build new instance of `MyDataObj` per user;
Then run job that updating some data in `MyDataObj` every minute;
Using `lockObj` as lock, lock the data to all the users (Although it's not static Variables)
I need only to lock the data to the current user

this is the code sample

```
public sealed class MyDataObj
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<object, MyDataObj> _instances = new Dictionary<object, MyDataObj>();
    public object lockObj = new object();
    public bool jobRunning = false;
    private string data = string.Empty;
    //// --------- constractor -------------------
    private MyDataObj(int key)
    {
        LoadMyDataObj(key);
    }

    public static MyDataObj GetInstance(int key)
    {
        lock (_instances)
        {
            MyDataObj instance;
            if (_instances.TryGetValue(key, out instance))
            {
                instance = _instances[key];
                return instance;
            }
            instance = new MyDataObj(key);
            return instance;
        }
    }

    private void LoadMyDataObj(int key)
    {
        // get the data from db

    }


    public void UpdateMyData(string newData)
    {
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            this.data = newData;
        }
    }
    public string ReadMyData()
    {
        lock (lockObj)
        {
            return this.data;
        }
    }



    public class ActionObject
    {
        MyDataObj myDataObj;
        int UserID;
        //// --------- constractor -------------------
        public ActionObject(int userid)
        {
            this.UserID = userid;
            myDataObj = MyDataObj.GetInstance(userid);
            if (!myDataObj.jobRunning)
            {
                jobs jbs = new jobs(myDataObj);
                System.Threading.Thread RunJob = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(jbs.dominutesAssignment));
                RunJob.Start();
                myDataObj.jobRunning = true;
            }
        }
        public ActionObject()
        {
            myDataObj = MyDataObj.GetInstance(this.UserID);
            myDataObj.UpdateMyData("some data");
        }
    }


    public class jobs
    {
        MyDataObj myDataObj = null;

        public jobs(MyDataObj grp)
        {
            this.myDataObj = grp;
        }
        public void dominutesAssignment()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                myDataObj.ReadMyData();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the term "lock" here?

Comment: Can you post the code of how you are locking currently?

Comment: Your code is terribly confusing. The `MyDataObj` class contains a static dictionary of `MyDataObj` instances and methods that access it, instance methods and properties that are accessed internally, and also some nested classes that access the `MyDataObj` methods. If a co-worker or employee asked me to help debug this, the first thing I'd tell him is to refactor it. As it stands, it's way too difficult trying to figure out who has access to what, and how all the different parts interact.

Comment: tnx Jim for your response. I use [Multiton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern). (The static dictionary purpose is to insure every user has access to his one instance of MyDataObj and that is why the MyDataObj has private contractor). The ActionObject do 2 things 1) starting job that use MyDataObj, 2) do some actions on the MyDataobj. I just need to prevent the job from interrupting the ActionObject if it's the SAME user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need a way to lock c# threads by user. I have my data object and I create new instance for every user

Create one lock per user. Or if the user exists longer than the threads: Use the user object as the lock.

```
lock (userOrTheUserObject)
{
    //Do some op
}
```

> Every user has several threads that use this object and in I.O. operations

That sounds more like you should use asynchronous IO instead of creating several threads (which will be less effecient)

> I want to lock this object instance for this user only. Using simple Lock {} is locking all the object instances, there for blocking other user.

If the object is shared between all users you HAVE to lock it using `lock`. The lock won't be very effective otherwise. The other object is to redesign the object to now be shared.

> I need some simple solution.

There are no simple threading solutions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Monitor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de0542zz.aspx). In this sample anyone but user 1 can execute DoIt method concurrently. While user 1 executing DoIt no one can enter it. A weak point is if user 1 tries to execute DoIt when user 2 already executing it, user 2 continues its execution. Also you have to handle exceptions properly otherwise there may be dead locks.

```
private static readonly object lockObj = new Object();

public void Do(int userId)
{
     Monitor.Enter(lockObj);

     if (userId != 1)
          Monitor.Exit(lockObj);

     try
     {
        DoIt();
     }
     finally 
     {
         if (userId == 1)
             Monitor.Exit(lockObj);
     }
}

public void DoIt()
{
    // Do It
}
```

Comment: ... wow - this code reminds me of how needed `try`&`finally` are. What if `DoIt()` fails with an exception? The lock will remain, which leads to a deadlock-scenario. Also: Why not simply use `lock ()` here (which would, in fact, solve the problem with the `try`&`finally`)?

Comment: The truth is: If you'd use `lock()`, there would be *no* chance for a *simple* deadlock-scenario.

Comment: Because he wants to change lock scope according to user dynamically and I cannot find a way to implement it with `lock`

Comment: you could :) ... what about an `if`/`else` :)

Comment: Anyway: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/de0542zz.aspx `Use a C# try…finally block (Try…Finally in Visual Basic) to ensure that you release the monitor, or use the C# lock statement (SyncLock statement in Visual Basic), which wraps the Enter and Exit methods in a try…finally block.` - I would add this excerpt :)

Comment: tnx for the answer, I need it to work for more then 1 user, so i need to manage the users that currently lock the object